# Is there an uncountable family of infinite parts of $\mathbb N$ with two to two intersection finite?

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

> Is there an uncountable family of infinite parts of $\mathbb N$ with
>   two to two intersection finite?

If the two to two intersections are empty, it is false; if not $\mathbb N$ would be uncountable.

What about this case?

Comment: Yes. Look up "almost disjoint families".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sets with finite intersection are called "almost disjoint".

View *functions* $\mathbb N\to\mathbb N$ in the usual ways as subsets of $\mathbb N\times\mathbb N$. This allows us to speak about whether two functions are almost disjoint.

If we have any *countable family* of functions, it is an easy diagonalization exercise to produce a new function that is almost disjoint from each of them.

On the other hand, Zorn's lemma proves that there is a *maximal family* of pairwise almost disjoint functions. By the previous paragraph, such a family cannot be countable.

This gives us an uncountable family of pairwise almost disjoint infinite subsets of $\mathbb N\times\mathbb N$. Since $\mathbb N\times\mathbb N$ is in bijective correspondence with $\mathbb N$, we can map this back to an uncountable family of pairwise almost disjoint subsets of $\mathbb N$.

Comment: The accepted answer to the duplicate question Asaf identified is better and simpler than this one; it does not depend (essentially) on choice.